# How To Communicate Three NodeMcu In Access Point Mode

Tags: esp8266, wifi, communication, nodemcu

I'm working on project which for example 3 nodemcu connected with eachother in a line(1 connected to 2 and 2 connected to 3) and they are all in access-point mode (they are all server) and now my problem is how to communicate between 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 i have tried tcp but its for server-client

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Look at the WiFi library. The function WiFi.mode() can set your NodeMCU as access point, station or both access point and station (WIFI_AP, WIFI_STA, WIFI_AP_STA or WIFI_OFF).

In the mode WIFI_AP_STA, your NodeMCU works both as access point and as a station independently; no need for special considerations.

You still need to know the IP address of each NodeMCU to make them to talk to each other. You can configure things to get fixed IP for each NodeMCU as a station.